# Jquery Validation somente após dropdown ser selecionado

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

Tenho um dropdown e quero validar, deixar ele obrigatório apenas se um checkbox for marcado, caso contrário ele não é obrigatório

Tentei fazer conforme JSFiddler
https://jsfiddle.net/dorathoto/zoh72rx5/6/

```
<form action="#" method="post" id="Form">
<input type="checkbox" id="L3chk" name="L3chk" value="true"  />
<select id="RadioId" class="form-control" >
  <option disabled selected>--- Selecione ---</option>
  <option value="1">Opc 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opc 2</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Enviar</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Form").validate({
                rules: {
                    RadioId: { required: "#L3chk:checked" }
                }
            })
        });
```

Comment: Mas não precisa do validate só para isto, isto faz só com jQuery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O jQuery Validation trabalha com o atributo `name`

> Nota: atributo `name` é necessário para todos os elementos de entrada
>   que precisam de validação, e o plugin não funcionará sem isso. Um
>   atributo `name` também deve ser exclusivo para o formulário, pois é
>   assim que o plug-in rastreia todos os elementos de entrada.

**Fonte**

> https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-markup-recommendations

**Exemplo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Form").validate({
    rules: {
      RadioId: {
        required: "#L3chk:checked"
      }
    },
    messages: {
      RadioId: {
        required: 'Campo obrigatório',

      }
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form action="#" method="post" id="Form">


  <input type="checkbox" id="L3chk" name="L3chk" value="true" />
  <select name="RadioId" id="RadioId" class="form-control">
    <option disabled selected>--- Selecione ---</option>
    <option value="1">Opc 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opc 2</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Como disse no comentário não precisa do **validate** para isto, no exemplo que fiz ao marcar o `checkbox` você automaticamente deixa o `select` com **required=true** e ao desmarcar o `checkbox` o select volta a ser **required=false**:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("select").prop("required", false);            // inicia o select com required false
  console.log("select NÃO obrigatório, envia o form.");

  $(".btn").on("click", function(event) {

      if($("#L3chk").prop("checked") == true) {    // se o checkbox estiver clicado
        $("select").prop("required", true);        // o select fica com required true
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("select obrigatório, não envia o form.");
      } else {
        $("select").prop("required", false);      // senão o select fica required false
        console.log("select NÃO obrigatório, envia o form.");
      }
    
  })
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="Form" action="https://www.google.com">

  <input type="checkbox" id="L3chk" name="L3chk" value="true"  />
  <select id="RadioId" class="form-control" >
    <option disabled selected>--- Selecione ---</option>
    <option value="1">Opc 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opc 2</option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: testei ai seu código e está fazendo o submit..não está exigindo selecionar..

Comment: Achei que só com que postei você implementaria a parte do **form**, mas, editei a resposta agora se o `select` for obrigatório o `form` não é enviado!

Comment: só um detalhe, não está enviando mesmo selecionado uma OPC 1